# Find total area under infinite curves

Tags: integration, area, curves

My question is finding the total area covered by curves, such as the total area every curve in the following picture covers (from 100 on y axis to 200 on x axis):

[image]

In my case, the curves are parabolas of trajectories described by $y = \frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_i \sin( \theta)t + y_0 $

This has probably been answered before, but I cannot find it. If there were 2 curves, the answer would be easy: just sum two areas and subtract the overlap.

Comment: Your title says infinite but the picture shows finitely many. Which do you want?

Comment: @Nitin infinite, the picture shows selected angles

Comment: @qwr these seem to be parabolas. You should say what kind of curves they are, and what are their equations (obvoiously they will be dependent on an auxiliary parameter).

Comment: You could find the maximum value in terms of the angle and smooth-out the "supremum" curve that's being formed. The area under that "supremum" curve is the limit of the areas under the finite plots.

Comment: To clarify and add to Nitin's comment,

Comment: What you want is called the "envelope" of the curves. Here is one place where they are discussed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)

Comment: @martycohen Thank you, I did not know how to describe it

Comment: Math is often like magic. In order to have power over something, you need to know its name.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this problem does not contain all the information it needs in order to be solved. While you made clear that you want the envelope of a certain family of parabolas  $y(x)=f_\theta(x)$, where $\theta=\arctan f'_\theta(0)$ and $f_\theta(0)=0$, these two conditions alone are not sufficient to uniquely determine $f_\theta$. In fact, if $f_\theta(x)=a_\theta x^2+b_\theta x + c_\theta$, you only get $\begin{cases}c_\theta=0\\ b_\theta=\tan\theta \end{cases}$, leaving $a_\theta$ completely arbitrary (though it is important when it comes to find the envelope)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I am looking for a general method to solve equations like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example 5 of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics),
it is shown that
the envelope of a 
family of parabolas
with constant initial velocity
and different initial angles
is also a parabola.

The equation is derived nicely.

Comment: A little clarification on the derivation would be helpful (how is the equation converted to implicit form and $\theta$ eliminated?)

Comment: Have you looked at the article? You need to read the initial sections and that particular section.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Nitin's comment, suppose that $f_\theta(x)$ denotes the curve with parameter ("angle") $\theta$ (in radians). Supposing that your variable $x$ never exceeds $200$, you want

$$\int_0^{200} \sup_{\theta\in[0,\pi/2]} f_\theta(x) dx$$

This of course depends on the equations $f_\theta(x)$.